# How to give validation in excel cell so that it accept only numbers and "," and "-" but no alphabets

Tags: vba, excel

I want to provide a validation in Excel cells where it accepts only numbers and comma(,) and hyphen (-) but no alphabets.

e.g, 1) 123
     2) 1223456-1223498
     3) 123456789,986532452

is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Definitely.  There are tons of examples of this.  Have you done any searches yet?  Also, please include any code you've written, what error you've been encountering or what progress you've made, etc.

Comment: I have searched so many examples. Couldnt find like this.As comma and Hyphen are considered as text it cant be accepted if i make the cell only numreic.Thats where I am facing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ALL TESTED:**

**As a Function:**
Returns True or False based on the argument passed to it as a string.

```
Function ValidateNumber(tempVal As String) As Boolean
Dim result As Boolean  
    tempVal = Replace(tempVal, "-", "")   'remove all hyphens
    tempVal = Replace(tempVal, ",", "")   'remove all commas

    'what is left of tempVal at this point is to be tested.  
    If (Not IsNumeric(tempVal) And (tempVal <> "")) Then
        result = False
    Else
        result = True
    End If   
    'Function returns True or False
    ValidateNumber = result    
End Function
```

**Sub to Call Function:**
Pass the string to test through the function and it returns True or False.  Call this from whatever event handler you have to launch the code.  Like a button click, or Cell.Text_change event.

```
Sub DataValidation()
Dim check As Boolean
Dim tempVal As String

    tempVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Text
    check = ValidateNumber(tempVal)  'Checking Sheet1!A2

    If check = True Then
        MsgBox (tempVal & " Passed Validation")
        'Insert your code here.
    Else
        MsgBox (tempVal & " isn't a valid number.  Input only numbers, commas, hyphens")
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1) = ""     'Clear the Cell of the invalid entry.
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Select   'Return the focus to the cell in question.
    End If
End Sub
```

**As an InputBox and MessageBox Test:**
This can be run independent of a Worksheet.  Using an Input Box to get the test value, and a message box to display the results.

```
Sub ValidateNumberCheck()
Dim cellVal As String
Dim tempVal As String

    cellVal = InputBox("Input some text to check", "Validation Check")
    tempVal = Replace(cellVal, "-", "")
    tempVal = Replace(tempVal, ",", "")    

    If (Not IsNumeric(tempVal) And (tempVal <> "")) Then 
        MsgBox ("Not a valid character.  Please input only numbers, commas, or hyphens.")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Input Passed Validation.") 
    End If
End Sub
```

**note:**  Be sure to remember, with that last example if you used it, you are using cellVal, not tempVal.  We are just testing tempValue because it's known to be a copy of cellVal, but by the time it makes it through this, all the commas and hyphens have been removed, and it would need re-formatted.  So instead of going through all of that, you still have that preserved original cellVal variable storing the original input.

Comment: Thank You Rosenburg. Appreciate your help :)